# explain me the concept of heterogeneous hardware in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

which one is commonly used heterogeneous or homogeneous and why ?

Comment: Homogeneous is preferred... Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194472/should-hadoop-clusters-run-on-identical-hardware

Answer (score 2):

Acc to Wikipedia -
Heterogeneous computing refers to systems that use more than one kind of processor or cores. These systems gain performance or energy efficiency not just by adding the same type of processors, but by adding dissimilar coprocessors, usually incorporating specialized processing capabilities to handle particular tasks.

It's because hadoop works in a cluster and a cluster can have any numbers of node and each node can have different type of hardware configuration like for example if a cluster consist of 2 nodes then it's possible that one node have 6 GB of RAM another have 8 GB of RAM or some other configuration. Point is that there is no restrictions on cluster to have same hardware configuration which enable hadoop to satisfy definition of heterogeneous hardware.

Comment: There could be a software limitation that requires particular hardware, though, so a purely random heterogeneous setup isn't going to work

Comment: Yes there could be, but that is also going to be minimum requirement

Comment: Unless the resource management properties are tuned properly, it is not going to work. Even if tuned, it could very much affect the parallelism. I believe heterogenous setup is still in research for hadoop.